# " org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution"

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I was trying to create new Gradle project in Eclipse IDE. But i got following exception " org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-bin.zip'."

Can anyone please help me out ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as workaround, please try to decreese spring boot version in build.gradle.
Use springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE' for example

Answer (score 0):

Choose in Eclipse preferences gradle version more then 4.

[image]